# HTML/CSS/Javascript delete button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a list of items inside a div that is determined by the contents of two arrays.

```
product_codes=[code1, code2, code3];
quantities=[1, 34, 67,];
```

Every time a new code and quantity is added to its respective array, I have a javascript function that does this:

```
    document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML='';
    cart_text='';
    elf='<br class="none"/>';
    for(i=0; i<product_codes.length; i++){
        cart_text+=(product_codes[i]+"  (x"+quantities[i]+")"+elf);
    }
    document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML=cart_text;
```

and acts upon This HTML:

```
<div id='cart_body'></div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.none{margin-top: 0px;}
```

(the CSS simply overrides another styling I gave to ALL 
 tags)

What I want to do, is at the end of each line added to cart_text (before the inserted line break), is to add a small circular button with an x in the center (I imagine that there's something like that in Bootstrap, but I am unable to use it or any other libraries) that when clicked, deletes the text next to it ON THAT LINE ONLY (the product code and quantity) from the div, AND deletes the two items(product code and quantity) from their respective arrays. Ideally, the aforementioned delete button would look something like the button that lets you delete a your comment that you've posted(here on Stack Overflow).

## Please only Vanilla CSS and Javascript answers only. No libraries, please.

If it's not too much to ask, a  working JsFiddle would be great too.

Thanks!

## Edit

Attempt at the button: #1

```
#close_button{
 border:  1px solid black;
 padding-top: 0;
 max-width: 15px;
 max-height:  15px;
 background-color: lightBlue;
 border-radius: 90px;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align:  center;
}

<div id='close_button'>x</div>
```

This does not work because I cannot get a proper size with the x in the exact center of the circle. I tried padding, all that good stuff, but to no avail.

Comment: You haven't shown us your attempt at this, though. People here are much more willing to fix your broken code than come up with a standalone implementation of only an idea, when you could do most of that yourself.

Comment: If you at least show what you have tried in relation to your problem. Most of the stuff youre looking to do is relatively simple and could be found using google.

Comment: @Craicerjack this isn't for a job, this is for something I'm building for myself.

Comment: To questions for you Mr. Chameleon. First, why are you storing these values in two separate arrays, rather than in an associative array? Second, why are you "unable to use [Bootstrap] or any other libraries"?

Comment: @Kwarrtz because of the way that this will be online, I cannot add libraries. I don't want to go in-depth as to why I can't, as it's not important. Please accept that i need a non-library answer as a main premise of the question.

Comment: Very well. Can you answer my first question?

Comment: @Kwarrtz I'm doing it that way just because I chose to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code at https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/krrhvdmj/

```
<div id='cart_body'>
<p>
  code1 x1 <span style="display:inline-block;width:30;height:30;background-color:#d2d2d2; border-radius: 50%;font-size:12px;line-height:18px;">X</span> 
</p>
```

```
  var product_codes=["code1", "code2", "code3"];
 var quantities=[1, 34, 67,];

   document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML='';

for(i=0; i<product_codes.length; i++){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_codes[i] +"     X    "+quantities[i]));
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    span.classList.add("delete");
    var a = document.createAttribute("data-productCode");
      a.value = product_codes[i];
    span.setAttributeNode(a);
    p.appendChild(span);
     span.addEventListener("click",removeElm);
  document.getElementById('cart_body').appendChild(p);
     }

function removeElm(){
    var div = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    for(i=0; i<product_codes.length; i++){
        if(product_codes[i] == this.getAttribute("data-productCode"))
        {product_codes.splice(i,1);
           quantities.splice(i,1);
        console.log(product_codes);
         console.log(quantities);
            break;
        }
    }
    div.removeChild(this.parentNode);

}
```

css Code

```
.delete{
  display: inline-block;
     width: 19px;
    height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
  background-color: #D2D2D2;
    border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
    }
```